# Powershell - Unable to Compare Strings Output from Sharepoint List

Tags: arrays, powershell, sharepoint

After extracting a list from SharePoint, I need to validate each Item against its `BRTeam` value. Here is the script:

```
cls
if((Get-PSSnapin | Where {$_.Name -eq "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"}) -eq $null) {
     Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell;
}

$sourceWebUrl = "http://theoracle/WorkingHere/"
$sourceListName = "Policies & Procedures"

$spSourceWeb = Get-SPWeb $sourceWebUrl
$spSourceList = $spSourceWeb.Lists[$sourceListName]

$spSourceItems = $spSourceList.Items

$spSourceItems | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host $_['Name']
    Write-Host $_['BRTeam']
}
```

The code works fine in terms of getting the data and writing the required items to the host.

However, if I add the following If-Statement to validate the items, I am seeing an error:

```
if ($_['BRTeam'].Contains('HR')) {
    Write-Host $_['Name']
    Write-Host $_['BRTeam']
}
```

I have also tried replacing the Boolean check with `$x -contains 'HR'` after assigning `$x = $_['BRTeam']`, but this returns no output (no error either). Error below:

```
Method invocation failed because [Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValue] doesn't contain a method named 'Contains'.
At line:21 char:9
+     if ($_['BRTeam'].Contains('HR')) {
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

Can anyone let me know what I am missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by using the `-Match` operator instead:

```
$spSourceItems | ForEach-Object {
    #Write-Host $_['ID']
    #Write-Host $_['Workflow Started']
    $x =  $_['BRTeam']

    if ($_['BRTeam'] -Match 'HR') {
        Write-Host $_['Name']
    }     
}
```

If I am concerned that some other BRTeams may contain `HR` without actually being HR, I could also perform a -NotMatch against all the other departments.

E.g.:

```
$spSourceItems | ForEach-Object {
    #Write-Host $_['ID']
    #Write-Host $_['Workflow Started']
    $x =  $_['BRTeam']

    if ($_['BRTeam'] -Notmatch 'Accounts' -And $_['BRTeam'] -Notmatch 'IT') {
        Write-Host $_['Name']
    }     
}
```

Comment: The reason `.Contains` didn't work is that the value of a field is an SPFieldValue Object, not necessarily a string. You can cast it to a string to display it, which is what Powershell does when you compare it to a string with `-match` or write it to the console with `Write-Host`. An alternative to using `-match` would be `$_['BRTeam'].ToString().Contains('HR')`